# Nginx Caching SSL Certificate?

Tags: linux, nginx, ssl, amazon-ec2

Previously(successfully), I had updated my SSL certificates in the same fashion as I tried to do this time. Like 2 files I have, `domain.chained.crt` and `domain.key`.

Then ran `sudo service nginx restart`, `sudo service nginx reload` and `sudo nginx -s reload` commands, the Nginx is still serving the old certificate. On Firefox when I click View Certificate it is showing an old one.

[image]

After that, I even changed the file name to `mydomain.chained1.crt` and `mydomain1.key`, then I also change the file names in `nginx.conf` like

```
ssl_certificate ssl/mydomain.chained1.crt;
ssl_certificate_key ssl/mydomain1.key;
```

After the changes, restarting and reloading nginx doesn't change the SSL certificate.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: It's far more likely that Firefox is caching the certificate.  Try in incognito mode or try a different browser.

Comment: I tried it on chrome and firefox, both in incognito modes, but same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to upload the latest certificate pem, chained, and key files on CloudFront too in the respective domain.

So the steps will be goto CloudFront -> Certificates. Select the desired domain then click on *Re-Import*.

Then put the latest pem, chained(optional), and key files.

So in total, in your case, 2 places where you have to update the certificates, which are Nginx and CloudFront. If you've got the certificate from AWS then you don't have to worry about CloudFront, because it auto-renews and auto-update.